# Why OpenCV gpu-module runtime library has huge size difference in Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, opencv, dll, shared-libraries, gpu

In Windows the size of the runtime library (dll) of the gpu module (opencv_gpu247.dll for OpenCV 2.4.7) has the enormous size of 417 MB. I checked the size of the same library in Linux (Debian repository) and in most architectures it is about 250 KB after installation. You can see it here https://packages.debian.org/stable/libs/libopencv-gpu2.3

Why is there such an enormous size difference in the same runtime library in different operating systems? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that OpenCV gpu module in Debian repository was built without CUDA and it is just a stub, where each function throws exception "Not available". 400 Mb is a real size of gpu module, which was built with CUDA support.